# MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, linkedin-api

I am trying to make a `JSONP` call in Angular 2, but every time I am getting this error:

> Refused to execute script from '[https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xyz&state=987654421n&callback=**ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished](https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xyz&state=987654421n&callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished)' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Below is my angular code:

```
let header = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

return this.jsonp.get('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xyz&state=987654421&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK', {
     headers: header
}).map(response => <string[]> response.json()[1]);
```

Comment: can you please `console.log(response._body)`? Even if it's a private property you can console.log it for debug purpose.

Comment: @Supamiu its coming null, because this request is not even firing, before making the call this error is coming

Comment: Oh I see, so can you add jsonp.get method implementation please?

Comment: @Supamiu what you mean by that? from here I picked up: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#cors

Comment: The URL you are requesting does not return JSONP, therefore the JSONP request fails.